# No header record was found when parsing with CSV Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

I seem to have run out of ideas on this issue. I have cut it down to as simple as possible, but i get the "No header record was found" error every time.

My CSV file

```
SIC,Description,Grouping
1,text,group
```

My model

```
public class SicCodeModel
{
    public string SIC { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Grouping { get; set; }
}
```

My map class

```
public sealed class SicCodeMap : CsvClassMap<SicCodeModel>
{
    public SicCodeMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SIC);
        Map(m => m.Description);
        Map(m => m.Grouping);
    }
}
```

The controller code

```
byte[] uploadedFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);

using (var reader = new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream))
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
{

     csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SicCodeMap>();

     var items = csvReader.GetRecords<SicCodeModel>().ToList();
}
```

My MVC model that is uploading the file

```
public class ImportModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

When I upload the file, it is there. But when the GetRecords runs, I get the error.

Thank you for any help. This seems like it should be super simple, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error happened because you read `model.File.InputStream` prior `CsvReader` and you didn't return position cursor in `InputStream` to prepare it for `CsvReader`.

After line: `model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadedFile, 0, uploadedFile.Length);` just call `model.File.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` and you won't see that error again.

Comment: Ran into the same one while trying to debug something to make sure parser is fed correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else that stumbles over this Post w/o actually properly reading the question (like me), [this](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/808#issuecomment-338425719) was actually the solution for me:

```
csv.Read();
csv.ReadHeader();
```

Example:

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(filepathToCsv);
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig);

csv.Read();
csv.ReadHeader();
var records = csv.GetRecords<MyType>().ToArray();
```

Hope that helps any poor lost souls like myself

Comment: I had this code. But this code also throws the exception when ReadHeader executed. Setting the position on the stream helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got this code to work. The only change was to the controller code. I got right from the uploaded file to StreamReader to the CsvReader. Working well so far.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(model.File.InputStream);

using (CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
{
      var stuff = csvReader.GetRecords<SicCodeModel>();
}
```